# Power Query keeps pulling in filtered-out data after a merge - How to stop?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have 3 columns: Item, Effective Date (the date of a pricing entry for the item) and Price.

I am trying to merge three queries based on a matching "Item" column. Each query has a certain date filtered out (one query with the most recent date for the Item, one query with a date that falls between a range, and one query with a date that is prior to 3/1/2023)

I can get my 3 data sets no problem, individually. However when I try to merge them all together based on the "Item", my dates start to pull in dates that are outside of my filtered results in the individual queries.

Example: ABC123 has 2/6/2024, 10/3/2023, and 1/2/2022 in the respective individual queries mentioned above. But when I merge them, the dates get flipped and instead of pulling the most recent date in query one, it displays 2/18/2018 which is the *oldest* date entry for ABC123, instead of the newest date entry that the individual query filters out.

I have these dates indexed based on a "Descending" sort on the Date column on a master sheet. And somehow I think this "Descending" date sort is getting removed or erased when I start to merge these sheets.

Here's how I was expecting this data to be displayed after my query merges: [Screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqpvk.png)

But the information I get back now displays dates that I have previously filtered out in the "individual" queries mentioned above.

Sorry - still kind of new to this, so here is the M code after the merge:

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(#"itemprice_mst - Master", {"item"}, #"itemprice_mst - Master (2)", {"item"}, "itemprice_mst - Master (2)", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded itemprice_mst - Master (2)" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "itemprice_mst - Master (2)", {"effect_date", "unit_price2", "Index"}, {"effect_date.1", "unit_price2.1", "Index.1"})
in
    #"Expanded itemprice_mst - Master (2)"
```

Here it is before the merge, on the table that I'm trying to merge to:

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("infor-query", "prod_app_data"),
    dbo_itemprice_mst = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="itemprice_mst"]}[Data],
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(dbo_itemprice_mst,{"item", "effect_date", "unit_price2"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Other Columns",{{"effect_date", type date}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"item", Order.Ascending}, {"effect_date", Order.Descending}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Sorted Rows", {"item"}, {{"Count", each _, type table [item=text, effect_date=nullable date, unit_price2=nullable number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn([Count],"Index",1)),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Custom", {"item", "effect_date", "unit_price2", "Index"}, {"item", "effect_date", "unit_price2", "Index"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom",{{"effect_date", type date}, {"unit_price2", type number}, {"Index", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type1", each ([Index] = 1))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Here's a screenshot of how it looks before I expand the merge - which is the *correct* data for what I'm looking for. It has the correct date for the "Current Eff Date" and the correct date for the "Middle Eff Date"

[Screenshot of Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tO7Th.jpg)

But as soon as I expand, here's what I get back, which is pulling in dates that I have previously filtered out.

[Expanded data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wt83.jpg)

Please let me know if I need to include anything else that can be helpful. **Also, I just realized that my M Code does not match up with my column names in my pictures. The M Code is what I'm actually working with, the column names in the pictures were changed just to help illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish and to show the difference between the two tables I'm trying to merge.**

Comment: There is no way a query pulls in data that does not exist, so there is something wrong with what you are doing.  And since you did not post your code, or a simple example we can use to help you, there is nothing we can do here

Comment: Welcome to the board.  Could you post the `M` code for the query.  The _Edit_ button is just below the tags at the bottom of your question.  Some sample data as table rather than a picture can help reproduce the problem.  Have a read of [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @horseyride - sorry, I'm still a bit new at this. I hope the edits I've made can be helpful in my question. Also, the data it's incorrectly pulling in *does* exist, it has just be previously filtered out. It's not making up new data that doesn't already exist somewhere.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - I have added the M Code that I hope will be helpful?

Comment: Sorry, that just seems impossible that the data before the expand is different from the data during the expand. It may be as issue with the preview function of powerquery. Try loading the data back to excel and see what you get